# OIDC Identity Provider design for SSO: should third party website handle authorization on their own?

Tags: authentication, oauth, openid-connect, openid

Let's say I'd like to develop my own OpenID Connect Identity Provider to let different website add a Single Sign On button to their login pages.
For example, `WEB A` and `WEB B` can connect to `MyIDP` to start the single sign on.

[image]

`WEB B` starts the OIDC flow. After user *authentication* on `MyIDP` and granting authorization over `MyIDP` frontend, user is redirected to `WEB B` with `id_token` (containing user info) and the `access_token`.
`WEB B` can now log in the user using the `id_token`.
Same thing applies for `WEB A`.

Now let's say that `WEB A` and `WEB B` has some functionalities which are restricted base on roles... for example `WEB A` backend APIs require roles `manager` and `user` and `WEB B` backend APIs require role `consultant`. So each website has its own real/domain role.

My question is:
should my OIDC Identity Provider `MyIDP` issue an `access_token` with these specific roles, so `MyIDP` should always acknowledge each third party website and all of the possible roles (store them in the database and let websites ask for them)? Is this why the OIDC protocol expects an `access_token` to be generated?
Or is the `access_token` specifically related to endpoints on the `MyIDP` itself and each platform should handle their own roles for the new user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether the applications want to use your IDP only to authenticate users, or also to authorize them.

In the first case, the apps manage their users separately and only use the SSO of your IDP to authenticate the user. E.g. `WEB A` will log in `user1` and will get an ID token for that user. It will then create an account for `user1` and assign some roles. This information will then be used to access `WEB A`'s backend.

In the second case, when you want to use your IDP also for authorization, the IDP issues both an ID token and an access token, and that access token is used to access any backends. This will mean that the party that is in control of the IDP is also in control of the backend services that web applications A and B will call. The web app then requests certain scope from the IDP and the user can consent whether to grant that scope.

So it can be both ways — it depends on the architecture that you want to use.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, I could actually support both the cases. By instance if `WEB A` is a third party web app I don't have any information about I would only issue an ID Token, and if `WEB B` is my own web application (frontend for a service of mine) I could issue an Access Token  too with user roles. 
I'm more concerned with actually applying to the standard: is it ok to do this? Is the access token the one that `WEB B` can directly use to call `WEB B` backend APIs, or it should be issued another access token by `WEB B` backend itself?

Comment: Yes, it's ok and it's how it's usually done. As `WEB B` and `MyIDP` are both under your control, then `WEB B` should be using access tokens from `MyIDP`. It should not issue its own tokens, as token issuance should be centralised. `WEB A` is not part of your organisation, then it needs its own means of issuing access tokens. It relies on `MyIDP` only to authenticate users. `WEB A` can use your access tokens if it would need to access your APIs (e.g., `WEB B`'s backend)

Comment: Thank you very much, you were really helpful. Could you suggest me the right specification/resource to implement OAuth2 roles in JWT access_tokens? (in the case of `WEB B` -- `MyIDP`) I see some use the "group" claims, others use "scopes" for application-specific roles

Comment: It's totally up to you how you implement that, there is no standard way. We've written quite a lot about it at Curity: https://curity.io/resources/claims. In my opinion, you should put claims in your tokens that will allow your backends to make authorization decisions. `scope` is fine if your system is not big and complicated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and for mentioning curity. Very helpful, I'll check it out for sure :)